# Unable to setup floating IP using keepalived and VRRP

Tags: ip, high-availability, virtual-ip-address, keepalived

I've a ubuntu machine hosting two VMs, each of them running an application, for which i need to provide high availability, so i implemented a floating IP using keepalived and VRRP, But i cannot ping the master VM using the virtual IP from the host, it says destination host unreachable.

keepalived.conf for VM1:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 { 
    interface enp1s0 
    state MASTER                  #BACKUP here for VM2
    virtual_router_id 51 
    priority 200                  #100 in case of VM2
    advert_int 2 
    authentication { 
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass monkey 
    } 
    virtual_ipaddress { 
        192.168.122.150/24
    }
}
```

when i start keepalived service , it shows below messages:

```
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: Unknown keyword '}'
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: Unknown keyword 'virtual_ipaddress'
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: Unknown keyword '192.168.122.150'
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: Unknown keyword '}'
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: Unknown keyword '}'
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Dec 19 14:31:37 secondaryvm systemd[1]: Started Keepalive Daemon (LVS and VRRP).
Dec 19 14:31:39 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Dec 19 14:31:41 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Dec 20 01:55:40 secondaryvm Keepalived_vrrp[1419]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received advert with lower priori
~
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer, but ran into similar issue myself. I kept receiving an error saying "vrrp_track_process" is an unknown keyword, even though if worked on 1 VM and not other.
On looking in "man keepalived.conf", I noticed one VM had "vrrp_track_process" in it's documentation and other did not. Hence package / repo needed to be updated.
Very likely the current version of package installed doesn't support the keyword used.